# How to "fuzzy" match (misspelled) strings in a directory?

Tags: search, text

I would like to search a directory(tree) with textfiles for strings that are approximately similar to a certain string, similar to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching. I googles for "fuzzy search" and found fzf but its definition of "fuzzy" doesn't seem to be in line with the linked Wikipedia article?

I want to find misspelled words among a large number of textfiles and want the words (smart) ranked by how similar they are to the correct spelling. How do I do that? Can this be done with fzf?

(By "smart" I mean e.g., keys close to each other. If I search for "dog", "dof" is closer than "dop" because g and f are next to each other on the keyboard.)

Comment: About fuzzy testing better check this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing

Comment: Also you can't rely on keyboard layout, think about AZERTY, QUERTZ, Dvorak to name few.

Comment: "Fuzzing" is an error-forcing technique for stress testing input handling, and is not the tool you want. Use `agrep`. Read `man agrep` or https://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep

Comment: Your question might be improved if you provided an example showing what you want to do. `I want to find misspelled words among a large number of textfiles...` implies you are looking for a [spell checker](https://linuxhandbook.com/spellchecking-commands/)

Comment: @Seamus What is unclear about this `I would like to search a directory(tree) with textfiles for strings that are approximately similar to a certain string`

Comment: @waltinator Fuzzy has several meanings. C.f. the tool I mentioned in the question, fzf.

Comment: @d-b:  I was just trying to offer a suggestion to help you. But to answer the *Q in your comment*: There are several things in your posted Question that are unclear to me.

Comment: @Seamus That says more about you than about my question. Maybe you should add "junior" to your profile name.

Comment: @Seamus I will add "unix user since 1997" to mine.

Comment: @d-b: If you want a historical reference, I'd say this seems to suit you: "unix user since 1997, asshole since birth"

Comment: @Seamus As long as I am not an easily offended snowflake I am fine.

Comment: @d-b: In that case, I'm happy to swap insults with you.